# Restore of SQL Server database failing with "FILESTREAM feature is disabled, although it is enabled

Tags: filestream, restore, sql-server-2017

Update: This db-restore issue is resolved for me, but I still don't know why my db got corrupted or why I couldn't restore backups. Maybe restoring a good backup of my db made it possible to restore all subsequent backups? Maybe a Windows Update ran over the weekend and fixed it? Not putting my resolution as an answer as it does not explain what fixed it. Here is the original question:

I've recently twice had a database on my localhost become unexpectedly / unexplainedly corrupted, showing "(recovery pending)". The first time, I deleted the database and was able to restore an old backup of the database. I had to run a bunch of scripts to get it up to date, but it worked. I overwrote my backup with a new one once I got the db in good working order (by right-clicking the db in Object Explorer in SSMS, -> Tasks -> Back Up, and clicking OK (thereby accepting the default of a Full Recovery model and Backup type)). Now, the database has again died, so I deleted it and tried to restore my backup again. This time, restore fails with the following message:

> Restore of database XXX failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)  Additional information: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: FILESTREAM feature is disabled. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended).

Filestream is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager (`SQLServerManager14.msc`) -> SQL Server Services -> SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) -> FILESTREAM -> checked the 2 "Enable FILESTREAM..." checkboxes. I have a 2nd SQL Server instance as well, and the 2 checkboxes are checked for that one too.

Filestream is also enabled with full access in SSMS, by right clicking Properties -> Advanced on the SQL Server host name.

When I run the following lines against the master db of my SQL Server host instance, it says it's reconfiguring from 2 to 2 (so I think it's already set to 2):

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2  
RECONFIGURE
```

I also used SQL Server Configuration Manager to change both of my SQL Server instances' Log On settings to run as the Built-in LocalSystem account for both of my sql server instances, since a while ago there was a bug with Windows Creators' Update that required this (but shouldn't be necessary as the bug was fixed).

I am running SQL Server 2017 v14.0.1000.169, Developer Edition on Windows 10 Pro version 1903, OS build 18362.900.

** Windows Event Log Errors: **

- Thursday: "SQL Server is not ready to accept new client connections. Wait a few minutes before trying again..."
- Friday: "A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Blobstore' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation."
  Also on Friday there were a lot of MsiInstaller informational messages saying "Windows Installer reconfigured the product..." and naming various products.

** SQL Server Logs: **

- No logs Friday, the day I noticed the db was corrupt.
- Thursday - Various messages about the server being shutdown, then Error: 17054, Severity: 16, State: 1 and "The current event was not reported to the operating system error log. Operating system error = (null). You may need to clear the operating system error log if it is full."
- For a week prior to Thursday, many messages saying "A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out..." and some msg about unloading of AppDomains due to memory pressure.

Any ideas why I would be unable to restore my db backup? Many thanks!

Comment: SQL Server databases do not just become corrupted - it is very expensive enterprise grade system, if DB becomes corrupted, you need to investigate why (the most likely cause is hardware i.e. hard drive - check Windows event log for clues). Your biggest mistake though was overwriting your original back up file with a fresh one taken from a database running on a failing computer - recipe for disaster. I hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I assumed the first time that I had corrupted it by doing a force restart of my machine without shutting down SQL Server, but since it happened again without that recurring you may be right. I had other old backups, just not from the same point in time, and I got the same issue trying to restore those as with the recent backup, but In the end I also am not sure the backup was the issue. I found another backup and was able to restore that today, but then I went back and tried to restore the original backups again, this time it worked. No idea why, don't think I changed anything.

Comment: If your hardware is playing up then anything is possible. As mentioned before check your Windows Event Logs. They should contain Warnings/Errors if HD is failing (the exact error is vendor specific and they may appear a little cryptic at first but nothing Google cant resolve). Also check SQL Server Logs. FYI: one of the purposes of Transaction Log is to gracefully handle hard shutdowns i.e. once started up SQL Server will read the log and rollback any transactions bringing DB back to operational status.

Comment: I've added what I see in the logs above at the end of the question description. Looks like there was some memory pressure and an issue activating the Blobstore.

Comment: RE "blobstore": - never encountered this myself. You would have Google it yourself. RE "Various messages about the server being shutdown" - look into these in more detail (do they look like a regular shutdown or something forced it to shutdown). RE "sql server process memory has been paged out": your system does not have enough RAM. It **may** help to set SQL Server [max memory usage limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15).
On the bright side: Looks like your hardware is fine.

Comment: RE max memory usage: assuming your machine has enough RAM 8 - 16GB. Try setting SQL Server memory to half of the available RAM and ensure that you do not have too many programs open at any one time. If you have less than 8GB RAM, then you need to upgrade your system.

Comment: Many thanks! I have 32GB of RAM, but I do hit the machine pretty hard. I've just set the max memory to 16K. The shutdown messages sound normal to me. However, very sorry not to have seen them sooner but I realized I somehow missed the most relevant log messages to explain the restore failures: "FILESTREAM: failed to connect to kernel driver RsFx0501. <{1038F43D-3391-45F7-B1B3-BADF26459429}>Failed to initialize CFsaShareFilter: Error 0x80070015(-2147024875)", followed by "FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 2". Any idea why that might fail to connect?

Comment: RE "FILESTREAM": don't know, maybe [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/filestream-rsfx-driver-fails-to-load-after-installing-sql-server/ba-p/384865) will help.